# DataRow.Field<Model> ¿Cómo lo seteo?

Tags: c#

Dispongo de un modelo con la siguiente estructura:

```
public class ModeloUno
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre{ get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre{ get; set; }
}
```

Con una consulta a base de datos obtengo los campos de **ModeloUno** mas **Status** *(Id,Nombre,Descripcion,IdStatus y NombreStatus)* y los seteo de la siguiente manera:

```
var modelo= rows.Select(r => new ModeloUno
            {
                Id = r.Field<int>("ID"),
                Codigo = r.Field<string>("NAME"),
                Descripcion = r.Field<string>("DESCRIPTION"),
                Status = r.Field<Status>(???)
            });
```

**¿Cómo seteo Status si tiene múltiples campos?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente haz lo siguiente:

```
var modelo= rows.Select(r => new ModeloUno
        {
            Id = r.Field<int>("ID"),
            Codigo = r.Field<string>("NAME"),
            Descripcion = r.Field<string>("DESCRIPTION"),
            Status = new Status(){Id=r.Field<int>("IdStatus"), Nombre=r.Field<string>("NombreStatus")}
        });
```

Lo que se hace aquí es crear una nueva variable de tipo `Status` usando un [inicializador de objetos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer), que consiste básicamente en ir asignado a cada campo del objeto el valor inicial.

En este caso, lo que quieres es asignar a `Status.Id` el valor `int` que está en la columna `IdStatus`, y a `Status.Nombre` el valor `string` que tienes en la columna `NombreStatus`.

P.D. Te recomiendo encarecidamente que el nombre de la clase y el de la variable no coincidan (`Status`), eso puede llevar a muchas confusiones. Por otro lado, para el caso que expones no sería necesario crear la clase `Status`, podrías simplemente añadir `IdStatus` y `NombreStatus` como variables en `ModeloUno`. Otra cosa es que la relacion entre un `ModeloUno` y `Status` fuera de uno a varios. En ese caso, si tendría sentido crear la clase `Status` y almacenarla dentro de `ModeloUno` como `List<Status>`.